# There is a bug that changes the size of the file transferred from axios to django

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I am building a react frontend server and a django backend server.

I transferred the image file from react fronted to Django backend using axios.

However, the contents of the image file in the backend media folder are not visible.

So, I compared the size of the original file before transmission and the size of the transferred file in the media folder.

The size of the original file was 687,687, and the size of the transferred file was slightly increased to 687,870.

However, rather than transferring from a react frontend server,

www.localhost:8000/admin

I connected to django backend server admin and uploaded the file, and it was confirmed that it uploaded normally.

I think react axios seems to have some dummy data in the process of transferring files.

1. react axios frontend code.

```
export function uploadFile(file) {
    let url = `${ROOT_URL}/upload/${file.name}`;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file)
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
        return (dispatch) => {
            axios.post(url, formData).then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: UPLOAD_FILE,
                payload: response
            })
        })
```

2. django rest framework backend code

   - models.py

```
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

- serializer.py

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ("__all__")
```

- views.py

```
class FileUploadView(CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )

    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        print(file_obj.size)

        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I want to know why the file has increased in capacity and why the file is broken.
Help.

================================================

[Picture , Compare hex data of two files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JxDK.png)

Upload a picture comparing the hex values ​​of both files

The hex data in front of the transferred file.

content-disposition: form-data; name="" ..........

This seems to be the data that is transmitted. Not a PNG file.

The same thing happened when transferring files to postman as well as react axios.

I think I need to modify the code in the django backend. Please help me.

Comment: Can you check the two files - the original and the enlarged one? The size difference is about one byte in 3780; try comparing the hex dumps of the first 4 Kb of each file - or better yet, filter both files through hexdump, then run a `diff` of the two dumps.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

I compared the hex data of both files.

So I found that it stores all of the data, not the png file of the transferred data.

Do you have any idea how to fix my code?

Have a nice day. @LSerni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )
```

i deleted this code on views.py, and it work.

================================================

and. i tried many ways.

```
from django import forms
from .models import File

class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('file', )
```

create FileForm.

```
def fileUpload(request):
    form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    form.save()
```

it also work.

This time, it seems to be a chance to read the DRF document in detail in django.

I hope this article helps. For new developers like myself